# Native Animation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm very newbie when it comes animations in iOS so, how will you do something like this in the image natively? What are different options to achieve animations of this sort?

[image: Animation]

Answer (score 7):

Here is the Tutorial for exactly this animation: [Tutorial](http://robb.is/working-on/a-hamburger-button-transition/)

Comment: *literally* that animation - nice